# What permissions are needed to publish and edit Carbon workspaces?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-carbon

What permissions does a user need to manage the promoted workspaces in Carbon? Are these the same permissions required to edit individual workspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Carbon Administration

Carbon administrator permissions are required to publish and promote Carbon workspaces (i.e., choose which workspaces are displayed in the workspace switcher), as well as manage org-wide settings, such as whether or not Carbon is displayed in dark mode.

Carbon administrator permissions are granted via the Carbon Organization Administrator application permission in Control Panel and are organization specific. You may need to reach out to your platform administrator if you require these permissions.

### Editing Carbon Workspaces

Permission to edit Carbon workspaces is based on compass permissions of the workspace and is separate from administrator permissions. If a user has edit permissions on the compass resource, they are able to edit it in Carbon. If they have view permissions, they can view it but not edit it.